# Integral equality over $\mathbb{R}$ for measurable functions in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I originally asked a question about notation, but in view of PhoemueX's thoughtful answer, I have edited the title/question statement so that this question can more searchable in the future.

Given a measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|dx = \int_{[0, \infty)} |\{x : |f(x)| \geq \lambda\}| d\lambda$

Comment: $d\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure (RHS can be also written as $\int_0^\infty |\{x:|f(x)|\geq s\}| ds$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is** true. By Fubini-Tonelli, we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty |\{x \mid |f(x)| \geq \lambda\}| \, d\lambda &=& \int_0^\infty \int \chi_{|f(y)| \geq \gamma} (x,\lambda) \, d\mu(x) \, d\lambda \\ &=& \int \int_0^\infty \chi_{|f(y)| \geq \gamma} (x,\lambda) \, d\lambda \, d\mu(x) \\ &=& \int \int_0^{|f(x)|} 1 \,  d\lambda \, d\mu(x) = \int |f(x)| \, d\mu(x).
\end{eqnarray*}